# How to include vertical dots between two equations?

Tags: equations

How to include a vertical dots between two leftright arrows of equations, like in the picture below?

[image]

Here the code I used:

```
\[
{\tilde{\pi}}_{x,t}-\theta_{x}\tilde{\pi}_{x,t-1}=\frac{(1-\zeta_x \beta)(1 \zeta_x)}{\zeta_x (\widetilde{rmc}_{x,t}+\tilde{v}_{x,t})+\beta(E_t\tilde{\pi}_{x,t+1}-\theta_{x}\tilde{\pi}_{x,t})
\]

\Leftrightarrow


\Leftrightarrow


\[
{\tilde{\pi}}_{x,t}=\frac{\theta_{x}}{1+\beta \theta_{x}}\tilde{\pi}_{x,t-1}+\frac{\beta}{1+\beta \theta_{x}}E_{t}\tilde{\pi}_{x,t+1}+\frac{(1-\zeta_x \beta)(1-\zeta_x)}{\zeta_x(1+\beta \theta_{x})}(\widetilde{rmc}_{x,t}-\widetilde{P}^{X*}_t-\tilde{rs_t}+\tilde{v}_{x,t})
\]
```

and my output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `align` environment (from `amsmath`) and the `\vdotswithin` command from the `mathtools` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  {\tilde{\pi}}_{x,t} & - \theta_{x}\tilde{\pi}_{x,t-1} = 
  \frac{(1-\zeta_x \beta)(1 \zeta_x)}{\zeta_x} (\widetilde{rmc}_{x,t}+\tilde{v}_{x,t})+\beta(E_t\tilde{\pi}_{x,t+1}-\theta_{x}\tilde{\pi}_{x,t})\\
    & \Leftrightarrow\\
    & \vdotswithin{\Leftrightarrow}\\
    & \Leftrightarrow\\
    {\tilde{\pi}}_{x,t} & =\frac{\theta_{x}}{1+\beta \theta_{x}}
    \tilde{\pi}_{x,t-1} + 
    \frac{\beta}{1+\beta \theta_{x}} E_{t} \tilde{\pi}_{x,t+1} + 
    \frac{(1-\zeta_x \beta)(1-\zeta_x)}{\zeta_x(1+\beta \theta_{x})}(\widetilde{rmc}_{x,t}-\widetilde{P}^{X*}_t-\tilde{rs_t}+\tilde{v}_{x,t})
  \end{align*}

\end{document}
```

The output will look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another way of structuring the calculation using `gather` and `aligned` from the `amsmath` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
{\tilde{\pi}}_{x,t}-\theta_{x}\tilde{\pi}_{x,t-1}
=\frac{(1-\zeta_x \beta)(1 \zeta_x)}{\zeta_x} (\widetilde{rmc}_{x,t}+\tilde{v}_{x,t})
+\beta(E_t\tilde{\pi}_{x,t+1}-\theta_{x}\tilde{\pi}_{x,t})\\
\Leftrightarrow\\
\vdots\\
\Leftrightarrow\\
\begin{aligned}
{\tilde{\pi}}_{x,t}={}
&\frac{\theta_{x}}{1+\beta \theta_{x}}\tilde{\pi}_{x,t-1}
 +\frac{\beta}{1+\beta \theta_{x}}E_{t}\tilde{\pi}_{x,t+1}\\
&+\frac{(1-\zeta_x \beta)(1-\zeta_x)}{\zeta_x(1+\beta \theta_{x})}
  (\widetilde{rmc}_{x,t}-\widetilde{P}^{X*}_t-\tilde{rs_t}+\tilde{v}_{x,t})
\end{aligned}
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```